# Adjust Width of Master on MasterDetailPage in xamarin.forms App

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, master-detail

In xamarin-forms application, I want to change width of left side menu For android app. Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You cant currently adjust the width of the MasterDetailPage

Comment: Thanks @Artūras, Are you sure ? did you have any officiel documentation where mentioned that we cannot adjust the width of the MasterDetailsPage ?

Comment: Take a look at : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/57549/#Comment_57549